# Use TextEditingController in Riverpod ConsumerWidget

Tags: flutter, riverpod, texteditingcontroller

I have a `ConsumerWidget`, which I'm using to watch the state of a provider. Anyways everything is working, besides my `TextEditingControllers`. Whenever I type something into the text field and click the done button on the phone keyboard, the textfields goes empty again. I think this is due to the state of that widget. So my question is how do I use the `TextEditingController` inside the `ConsumerWidget`, which has no `createState` method?

Here is my code. Thanks in advance:

```dart
class MainPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ref) {
    // provider
    final roomListData = ref.watch(roomDataProvider);

    final roomService = RoomService();

    final roomIDController = TextEditingController();
    final roomPasswordController = TextEditingController();

    // UI screen size
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    double deviceWidth = size.width;
    double deviceHeight = size.height;

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: bluePrimary,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: roomListData.when(
              data: (data) {
                List<RoomModelResponse> roomList =
                    data.map((room) => room).toList();
                return SafeArea(
                    child: Container(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 36, vertical: 16),
                  child: Column(
                      //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              iconSize: deviceWidth * 0.09,
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.person_outline,
                                  color: orangePrimary),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            const DetailedProfilePage()));
                              },
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.add,
                                color: orangePrimary,
                              ),
                              iconSize: deviceWidth * 0.09,
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          const CreateRoomScreen()),
                                );
                              },
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      
                        SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.04),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text("Join room",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Chalet',
                                fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.05,
                                color: whitePrimary,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                              )),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.008),

                        // room ID textField
                        SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: roomIDController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: whitePrimary,
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                                hintText: 'Enter room ID to join it',
                                hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 174, 173, 173))),
                          ),
                        ),

                        SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.01),

                        // room password textField
                        SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                          child: TextField(
                            obscureText: true,
                            controller: roomPasswordController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: whitePrimary,
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                                hintText:
                                    'Leave blank if the room has no password',
                                hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 174, 173, 173))),
                          ),
                        ),

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use hooks (`flutter_hooks` package) and use `HookConsumerWidget`. Then your code will be even shorter. You will also need a package `hooks_riverpod`:

```dart
class MainPage extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ref) {

    final roomListData = ref.watch(roomDataProvider);

    final roomIDController = useTextEditingController();
    final roomPasswordController = useTextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(...);
  }
}
```

Hooks take care of the lifecycle of objects themselves, so you don't have to manually dispose of them via the `dispose` method.

Links:

- [flutter_hooks | Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks)
- [hooks_riverpod | Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod)
- [Level Up Your Flutter Development with Flutter Hooks](https://www.dhiwise.com/post/cracking-flutter-hook-an-advance-guide-for-flutter-devs)
- [Flutter Hooks | Medium](https://medium.com/@iamsureshsharma/overview-of-flutter-hooks-62b93eb721d9)

Answer (score 4):

You need to have StatefulWidget when working with `TextEditingController` since every time parameters of your widget change, it triggers `build()` method, which recreates your controllers, making them empty. Refer to [this part](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui#changing-widgets-in-response-to-input) of flutter guide.

When working with recent versions of riverpod you need to use `ConsumerStatefulWidget` which is exactly like `StatefulWidget` syntactically, but with "Consumer" before every class name.

Your resulting widget should create

```dart
// probably some other vars too
final roomIDController = TextEditingController();
final roomPasswordController = TextEditingController();
```

outside of the `build()` method, inside of _State class

Comment: Also don't forget to dispose of those controllers in your `dispose` method.

Answer (score 0):

Riverpod doesn't recommend using providers to store TextControllers. You can use  **ConsumerStatefulWidget** for the local state